# NTP server setup config

Tags: ntp

The most important thing is that my 2 machines are synced with each other. Of course all else being equal, I would like the shared time to be synced with some public server(s).

1. Is it ever prudent to avoid syncing the system with the outside world, because this results in worse sync between the machines?
2. Assuming I do wish to sync the system with the outside world, is it best to simply have the two machines serve each other, or should I concern myself with the `peer` configuration setting? I don't find the docs clear at all when it comes to the `prefer` keyword either. Doesn't it already prefer servers higher up the list?

Answer (score 0):

1 - That depends on your specific situation. In general if you can you should *always* sync to a valid set of time sources. These don't strictly speaking have to be 'external' you could deploy your own stratum 0 solution by way of a GPS/MSF/DCS/CDMA receiver and hard-wire that into a host you physically control. But generally speaking I can't think of any reason why two hosts would want to sync to each other but not anything 'valid' when there are usually options to allow that.

2 - Since it is only two machines then depending on the physical locations of the boxes it would be better to give them both there own valid config with at *least* 3 and *ideally* 5 external low stratum servers to connect to.

In a simple set-up like yours where your not providing a timing domain to an entire network or collection of hosts you can safely ignore the `peer` command.

For some info check the [docs](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.1/confopt.htm) If you had a setup as shown below then you could/would peer server A & B. This is just 1 example and in reality would include additional `peer`statements and cross connections.

```
    GPS (s0)                   DCFa (s0)
     |                          |
     v                          v
  Server A (s1) <---peer---> Server B (s1)
     |                          |
     v                          v
  Server C (s2)              Server D (s2)  
     |                          |
     v                          V
  London Clients             Dutch Clients
```

As for [prefer](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.1/prefer.htm) You should check the doc's its a tricky one;

> Marks the server as preferred. All other things being equal, this host
>   will be chosen for synchronization among a set of correctly operating
>   hosts. See the Mitigation Rules and the prefer Keyword page for
>   further information.

From the Mitigation Rules;

> In the prefer scheme the clustering algorithm is modified so that the
>   prefer peer is never discarded; on the contrary, its potential removal
>   becomes a termination condition. If the original algorithm were about
>   to toss out the prefer peer, the algorithm terminates immediately. The
>   prefer peer can still be discarded by the sanity checks and
>   intersection algorithms, of course, but it will always survive the
>   clustering algorithm.